# Return element's index in ArrayList<Object> that contains some field

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of say, this object:

```
class Object() {
    String name;
    double price;
    int id;
}
```

I want to find the index of the ArrayList that contains the element where the name field is equal to a given string. For example:

```
public int findIndex(ArrayList<Object> list, String name) {
    for(Object o : list) {
        if (o.getName().equals(name) {
            //return index
        }
    }
}
```

What's a good way to return the index?

Comment: *class Object()* Umm, what?

Comment: It's just an example, consider the class being called anything

Comment: Is it possible that more than one object may have the same value you're searching for? If so, do you want to return an array of indexes or only the first one?

Comment: The index of only the first one

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate the list with an indexed-for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { 
    if (list.get(i).getName().equals(name)) { 
        return i; 
    } 
} 
return -1;
```

Or simply use a counting variable when you want to use the for-each-loop:

```
int i = 0;
for(Object o : list) {
    if (o.getName().equals(name)) {
        return i;
    }
    i++;
}
return -1;
```

Or using Java-8 streams:

```
return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .filter(i -> list.get(i).getName().equals(name))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(-1);
```

You see that I returned `-1` when nothing was found. This is a common concept used throughout the java language.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can just do:

```
public int findIndex(ArrayList<Object> list, String name) {
    for(Object o : list) {
        if (o.getName().equals(name) {
            return list.indexOf(o);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

(-1 is returned if nothing was found).